# How to update client-side javascript cache with SmartGWT?

Tags: javascript, gwt, smartgwt

Defered javascript files loading is implemented easily on standalone login page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="<c:url value='/etgcrm/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="<c:url value='/etgcrm/sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="<c:url value='/etgcrm/sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js'/>"></script>
```

And so on.

That works fine until you decide to update SmartGWT javascript libraries.

Because SmartGWT itself is linking .js file by their original name, you can't just add version parameters to scripts paths on login page like

```
ISC_Core.js?ver=123
```

It is useless, because your browser will use cached scripts from

```
ISC_Core.js
```

as SmartGwt orders.

What is the most elegant way to overcome this problem?

P.S. Solutions including usage of FileLoader and other Power features are not suitable for me, i have ony PRO lecense.

Comment: If you are using GWT, you should not muck around with its deferment strategy. Regardless what SmartClient allows you independent of GWT. There is no point mucking around - just use GWT as-is and use GWT's source-code level delayed/lazy loading.